# How to add a background color to d3 text elements?

Tags: d3.js

I'm trying to add a rect element behind text with d3 to simulate background-color which doesn't exist for d3 text elements. I would like the rect to have the exact same size as the text itself.

```
node.append("text") 
    .attr("class", "text")
    .attr("text-anchor", "middle")
    .attr("dx", 0)
    .attr("dy", ".35em")
    .text(function(d) {
          var bbox = this.getBBox();
          node.insert("rect",":first-child")
          .attr("x", bbox.x)
          .attr("y", bbox.y)
          .attr("width", bbox.width)
          .attr("height", bbox.height)
          .style("fill", "yellow");
        return d.name;
    });
```

this.getBBox() returns 0 for both x and y.

The following code display the box, but it size doesn't very with text size, and the box is drawn even when text is not (when an image exists).

```
node.filter(function(d) {return (!d.image)}).append("text") 
    .attr("class", function(d) { return "text "+d.type; })
    .attr("text-anchor", "middle")
    .attr("dx", 0)
    .attr("dy", ".35em")
    //.text(function(d) { if (!d.imgB64) { return d.label; }
    .text(function(d) {
        return d.name;
    })
    .each(function(d) {
       var bbox = this.getBBox();
          node.insert("rect", "text")
          .style("fill", "#FFE6F0")
          .attr("x", bbox.x)
          .attr("y", bbox.y)
          .attr("width", bbox.width)
          .attr("height", bbox.height);
    });
```

**SOLUTION**

Thanks to Cool Blue, the following code now properly works: display a rect behind the text so that it is readable when larger than the node circle. In the futur it could be improved with a sphere arc rather than the rect to only hide the circle frame behind the text...

[image]

```
// only display node labels if node has no image 
node.filter(function(d) {return (!d.image)}).append("text") 
    .attr("class", function(d) { return "text "+d.type; })
    .attr("text-anchor", "middle")
    .attr("dx", 0)
    .attr("dy", ".35em")
    .text(function(d) {
        return d.name;
    })
    .call(getTextBox);

// only display a rect behind labels if node has no image 
node.filter(function(d) {return (!d.image)}).insert("rect","text")
    .attr("x", function(d){return d.bbox.x})
    .attr("y", function(d){return d.bbox.y})
    .attr("width", function(d){return d.bbox.width})
    .attr("height", function(d){return d.bbox.height})
    .style("fill", "#FFE6F0");

function getTextBox(selection) {
    selection.each(function(d) { d.bbox = this.getBBox(); })
}
```

Comment: What happens if you replace `box.x` with `d3.select(this).attr("x")`?

Comment: But anyway, the bounding box will be zero width and height because there is no text added yet. I would do it differently... See [this example](http://bl.ocks.org/cool-Blue/9f49525e782491c8b68a)

Comment: I managed to have it partly working by moving the code in an .each(function(d){ ... }) however there are still issues: the box always have the same size whereas I'd like it size to vary with the text size and it draws a box for each nodes, even those having no label (text). See code above.

Comment: Your code is quite complex, I'm not sure what to look for there. Do you use getBB to vary the node (circle) size based on the text length?

Comment: Yes, check out [this section](https://gist.github.com/cool-Blue/9f49525e782491c8b68a#file-script-array-base-js-L109) of the example I referenced and [here](https://gist.github.com/cool-Blue/9f49525e782491c8b68a#file-script-array-base-js-L149) and [here](https://gist.github.com/cool-Blue/9f49525e782491c8b68a#file-script-array-base-js-L155). You can temporarily store the svgRect returned by getBBox on the datum (d) of the text element and apply that to the rect selection in a seperate statement.

Comment: I use `glyph.call(getBB)` to put the BBox on the datum of each element and then I use `backGround  = node.select("circle").each(function(d){ d3.select(this).attr(makeCircleBB(d))})` to make the background elements. You can check out the [makeCircleBB](https://gist.github.com/cool-Blue/9f49525e782491c8b68a#file-script-array-base-js-L155) to see the final part...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, use this pattern and add whatever details you need...

```
var textNode = node.filter(function(d) {return (!d.image)})

textNode.append("text") 
    .attr("class", "text")
    .attr("text-anchor", "middle")
    .attr("dx", 0)
    .attr("dy", ".35em")
    .text(function(d) {
        return d.name;
    }).call(getBB);   
textNode.insert("rect","text")
    .attr("width", function(d){return d.bbox.width})
    .attr("height", function(d){return d.bbox.height})
    .style("fill", "yellow");

function getBB(selection) {
    selection.each(function(d){d.bbox = this.getBBox();})
}
```

Comment: This doesn't work for me, no error message but still no rectangle. Following you previous recommendations, I managed to get the proper box size with .call(getBB), now I need to insert the rect.

Comment: You need to add x and y attributes maybe. I thought they might be zero. Is node a g element with data bound by the way? Ah yes, I see the problem... The text is not there yet, yes, the seperate call is the way to go. I was trying to be too terse.

Comment: With .call(getTextBox) right after the .text() and then node insert as below, I get an error message evaluating d.bbox.width
 node.insert("rect","text")
  .attr("width", function(d){return d.bbox.width})
  .attr("height", function(d){return d.bbox.height})
  .style("fill", "yellow");

Comment: Yes node is a g element:  var node = svg.selectAll(".node")
  .data(nodes)
  .enter().append("svg:g")
  .attr("class", "node")
  .on("dblclick", dblclick)
  .call(force.drag);

Comment: Ok. You only hit that code one time? You don't need to allow for data update? If so you should seperate the update and enter selections. I updated my answer, still not working?

Comment: My mistake, I had this.each... instead of selection.each in the getBB function. Now it's working, many thanks.

Comment: Hmm, OK, that's strange.  `this === selection // true` in the code posted... I just used selection because its clearer.  Anyway, good that its working. Can you do us all a favour and share (post) your working code please? :)

Comment: Yes, I will post the working code, I still need to correct one more issue. I only draw labels (names) when the node has no image, which yet doesn't work because the rect element is not filtered as the text is... should take long even for the beginner I am.