# How to add a visible background color to d3 text elements?

Tags: javascript, angular, svg, d3.js

Currently, I am trying to put a background color behind my texts in my d3 sankey diagram.

Basically, I did it the same way as in this Stack Overflow example:

[StackOverflowExample](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32026194/how-to-add-a-background-color-to-d3-text-elements)

Unfortunately, the rectangle is not visible, although it is rendered into the elements.

Does anyone have any idea why this is?

Here is the snippet of my code:

```
this.nodes
  .selectAll('text')
  .data(this.data.nodes)
  .join(
    (enter) =>
      enter
        .append('text')
        .text((d) => `${d.name + ': ' + d.value}`)
        .style('fill', '#000000')
        .attr('text-anchor', 'right')
        .attr('x', (d, i) => {
          return d.x0 + (d.x1 - d.x0) / 0.5;
        })
        .attr('y', (d, i) => {
          return d.y0 + (d.y1 - d.y0) / 2;
        })
        .attr('dy', '0.35em')
        .attr('transform', (d, i) => {
          const x = d.x0 + (d.x1 - d.x0) / 2;
          const y = d.y0 + (d.y1 - d.y0) / 2;
          return `rotate(0, ${x}, ${y})`;
        })
        .call(getTextBox)
        .insert('rect', 'text')
        .attr('x', function (d) {
          return d.bbox.x;
        })
        .attr('y', function (d) {
          return d.bbox.y;
        })
        .attr('width', function (d) {
          return d.bbox.width;
        })
        .attr('height', function (d) {
          return d.bbox.height;
        })
        .style('fill', '#FFE6F0'),
    (update) =>
      update
        .transition()
        .duration(1000)
        .ease(d3_easeQuadInOut)
        .attr('x', (d, i) => {
          return d.x0 + (d.x1 - d.x0) / 2;
        })
        .attr('y', (d, i) => {
          return d.y0 + (d.y1 - d.y0) / 2;
        })
        .attr('transform', (d, i) => {
          const x = d.x0 + (d.x1 - d.x0) / 2;
          const y = d.y0 + (d.y1 - d.y0) / 2;
          return `rotate(0, ${x}, ${y})`;
        })
  );

function getTextBox(selection) {
  selection.each(function (d) {
    d.bbox = this.getBBox();
  });
}
```

Here is a picture of the rendered HTML elements from my browser:

[image: HTML Elements]

Here is an image of the sankey diagram. Each text should be with a grey background.

[image: d3 sankey diagram]

**Remark:**

I have made some progress, but the problem is still not solved.

It looks like when I use the “insert” function, the new element is always inserted as a child – Not as a **sibling.**

I still don't understand why this is, since the insert function should actually insert an element before the specified element - not in the specified element. In my case, it's the “text” element.

Comment: no such thing as a bg-rect in SVG. If you meant rect then it needs to be a sibling of the text elements (as it is in the linked question and its answers).

Comment: Thank u for your input. It's the same result with “rect”.

Comment: Did you read and understand the second sentence in my previous comment?

Comment: The example uses a textNode variable to ensure that the text and rect elements are siblings. You have them as parent and child. That's why the linked question's answers work and your question doesn't.

Comment: It is wrong what you say. The textNode variable only filters out elements that do not contain an image. That's it. However, when I apply an insert to my nodes, it causes the new elements to become children, not siblings. Exactly that is my problem. And I dont know why.